# Yii composite primary keys with isNewRecord

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a mysql table with composite keys ( user_id , category_id );
I am trying to update the last access for these records as following

```
$userCategory = new UserCategory;
$userCategory->user_id = 1;
$userCategory->category_id = 15;
echo $userCategory->isNewRecord; //always true
$userCategory->last_access = Now();

$userCategory->save();
```

The {$userCategory->isNewRecord} and when I try to save() the MySQL generates a duplicate error for the composite Primary keys.

I also added this to UserCategory model but didn't help

```
public function primaryKey() {
        return array('user_id', 'category_id');
    }
```

****Update:
Sorry for the confusion. My question is how to achieve the same result as "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" in the Yii framework. In other words, how to do the insert or update in one SQL query. if you look at the source code for [save()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail)

```
public function save($runValidation=true,$attributes=null)
{
    if(!$runValidation || $this->validate($attributes))
        //checking if new record
        return $this->getIsNewRecord() ? $this->insert($attributes) : $this->update($attributes);**
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Check the edit in my answer for populating the new record when applicable.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, the problem is that if `isNewRecord` is always true, it means that Yii is going to use an `INSERT` statement instead of an `UPDATE` statement when saving the model to the database.. that is why you always get the duplicate pk error, even if it's composite.

[**Here**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getIsNewRecord-detail) is the official documentation about `IsNewRecord` . So, the problem is that you're using

```
$userCategory = new UserCategory; //Always a new record, tries to INSERT
```

So to resolve this you have to find the record and evaluate if it is found before saving it, instead. Documentation can also be read [**Here**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#find-detail) about the `find()` family of methods and their return value, the return values of the find() methods vary slightly on their nature:

> find..() returns the record found or `NULL` if no record is found.
>
> findAll..() returns an array containing all the records found or an empty array if no records are found.

You can use this return value to differentiate wether a primary key exists or not:

```
$userCategory = UserCategory::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id '=>1,'category_id '=>15));
// if user does not exist, you need to create it
if ($userCategory == NULL) {
     $userCategory = new UserCategory;
     $userCategory->user_id = 1;
     $userCategory->category_id = 15;
}
echo $userCategory->isNewRecord; //you will see the difference if it does exist or not exist
$userCategory->last_access = Now();
$userCategory->save();
```

This will ensure that the framework uses the INSERT or UPDATE statement correctly, avoiding the duplicate PK error you're getting.

**Edit:** Enhanced the example code to properly populate the record when it's new.

Answer (score 3):

In your model, add the following method:

```
/**
* Uses the primary keys set on a new record to either create or update
* a record with those keys to have the last_access value set to the same value
* as the current unsaved model.
*
* Returns the model with the updated last_access. Success can be checked by
* examining the isNewRecord property.
*
* IMPORTANT: This method does not modify the existing model.
**/

public function updateRecord(){
  $model = self::model()->findByPk(array('user_id'=>$this->user_id,'category_id'=>$this->category_id));

  //model is new, so create a copy with the keys set
  if(null === $model){
    //we don't use clone $this as it can leave off behaviors and events
    $model = new self;
    $model->user_id = $this->user_id;
    $model->category_id = $this->category_id;
  }

  //At this point we have a model ready for saving, 
  //and don't care if it is new or not
  $model->last_access = $this->last_access;
  $model->save(false);
  return $model;
}
```

The above is inspired by a more general method that I use a lot to do a create-or-find-if-already-exists process.

Use the following code to execute this.

```
$userCategory = new UserCategory;
$userCategory->user_id = 1;
$userCategory->category_id = 15;
echo $userCategory->isNewRecord; //always true
$userCategory->last_access = Now();

$userCategory = $userCategory->updateRecord();
```

Note that only the last line is different from your code. The fact that the instance of the model declared with `new UserCategory` is not altered is intended behavior.

You can then verify in your code whether or not the model saved with the following:

```
if(!$userCategory->isNewRecord){
  echo 'save succeeded';
}
else{
  echo 'save failed';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to update, you should load record, instead of creating a new one.

```
UserCategory::model()->findByPk(array('user_id'=> 1,'category_id '=> 15));
$userCategory->last_access = Now();
$userCategory->save();
```

Comment: I do not know if I am updating or inserting. I need to insert if it's a new record otherwise update, similar to "on duplicate update"

Comment: There are two different functions within your controller for this, handle updates in actionUpdate and inserts in actionCreate

Comment: I am not talking about the controller! it is a different process

Answer (score 1):

in UserCategory.php

```
public function isNewRecord()
{
    $result = $this->findByAttributes(array('user_id'=>$this->user_id,'category_id'=>$this->category_id));
    if($result === NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

then in the controller

```
$userCategory = new UserCategory;
$userCategory->user_id = 1;
$userCategory->category_id = 15;
echo $userCategory->isNewRecord(); 
----
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to modify the model to change the condition on the save function then call the parent save function: (this code goes in the UserCategory model)

```
public function save($runValidation=true,$attributes=null) {
    $exists = UserCategory::model()->findByAttributes(array('category_id'=>$this->category_id,'user_id'=>$this->user_id));
    if($exists) {
        $this->isNewRecord = false;
    }
    return parent::save($runValidation,$attributes);
}
```

I just did a test and it seems to work correctly. You should just be able to do this:

```
$userCategory = new UserCategory;
$userCategory->user_id = 1;
$userCategory->category_id = 15;
$userCategory->last_access = Now();
$userCategory->save();
```

Should insert or update based off of whether it finds the record, so you don't have to change any of your other code.

Comment: FYI I tried to do this on beforeSave() first. However when the save() function ran for some reason the isNewRecord was reset to true.